# Ruby on Rails 3: How to override/change as_json serialization for ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, datetime, serialization, timezone

When Rails3 serializes ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone to json that dates look something like this:

**"2011-07-20T23:59:00-07:00"**

... it should be ...

**"2011-07-20T23:59:00-0700"**

That last colon is problematic when trying to convert that string using [standard date formatting patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns) ... none of them account for the use of a colon!

So my question is, "How do I override/change the serialization for TimeWithZone so that as_json returns a valid string that can be understood using the standard date format patterns?"

Right now I have to strip that last colon out in my client app but that just seems pooch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), but hey it is Ruby and that is allowed.

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def to_json
      super.gsub(/:(?!.*:)/,'')
    end
  end
end
```

Tested by running:

```
Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
Time.zone.now.to_json # Outputs -> 2011-09-22T16:46:28-0400
```